# AWS Elastic Beanstalk requires SQLite 3.8.3 or higher for Django Application

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am trying to upload a Django application on AWS Elastic Beanstalk.
I used the following tutorial:

- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create-deploy-python-django.html

But I end up with the following error message after login attempt on /admin

```
NotSupportedError at /admin/login/
deterministic=True requires SQLite 3.8.3 or higher
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://django-env50.eba-3ipauf3e.us-west-2.elasticbeanstalk.com/admin/login/?next=/admin/
Django Version: 3.1.7
Exception Type: NotSupportedError
Exception Value:    
deterministic=True requires SQLite 3.8.3 or higher
Exception Location: /var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py, line 215, in get_new_connection
Python Executable:  /var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/bin/python
Python Version: 3.8.5
Python Path:    
['/var/app/current',
 '/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/bin',
 '/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/bin',
 '/usr/lib64/python38.zip',
 '/usr/lib64/python3.8',
 '/usr/lib64/python3.8/lib-dynload',
 '/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/lib64/python3.8/site-packages',
 '/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/lib/python3.8/site-packages']
Server time:    Mon, 29 Mar 2021 16:23:05 +0000
```

Here is the Pipfile:

```
[[source]]
url = "https://pypi.org/simple"
verify_ssl = true
name = "pypi"

[packages]
asgiref = "==3.3.1"
pytz = "==2021.1"
sqlparse = "==0.4.1"
Django = "==3.1.7"

[dev-packages]

[requires]
python_version = "3.8"
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Encounters with the same issue can you please tell me how you resolved this?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. The solution was posted below. I hope that it can help you.

Answer (score 1):

Switching to Python 3.7 seems to fix the problem.

```
[[source]]
url = "https://pypi.org/simple"
verify_ssl = true
name = "pypi"

[packages]
asgiref = "==3.3.1"
pytz = "==2021.1"
sqlparse = "==0.4.1"
Django = "==3.1.7"

[dev-packages]

[requires]
python_version = "3.7"
```